# Sorting (DESC/ASC) the data from Database and sending them using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, sorting

I'm trying to sort the data from my database and store them in JSON. This is the query that I'm using to fetch data in DESC order

```
   $fetch_post_query = "SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE userid = 'Jhon' ORDER BY 'post_id' DESC ";
```

and
             echo json_encode(xyz); to show data. But no matter if the query is for DESC or ASC, the data is displayed in the order it was stored in database.

I've checked the other answers related to sorting the data but nothing seems to be working for me.

[image: Database Structure]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing quote from post time :

```
$fetch_post_query = "SELECT * FROM user_post WHERE userid = 'Jhon' ORDER BY post_time DESC";
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: can you describe your table schema with some data which have userid John?

Comment: did you check my given query in your phpmyadmin?